# Searching if a date is in an event

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a db table with a list of events
e.g.

```
starteventX = 2019-02-20 endeventX = 2019-03-15
starteventY = 2019-03-11 endeventY = 2019-05-28
```

I need to know if year 2019 and month 04 are in the event so I can prepare a monthly report

I tried

```
$mainlink = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM eventi WHERE ((year1 >= '$year') OR (year2 <= '$year'))
        AND ((month1 >= '$month') OR (month2 <= '$month')) ") or merror($msg = mysqli_error($db));
```

but cant get the required info

Comment: That's confusing. Why are there full dates in the description of what you have but `year1`, `month1` etc. columns in the query? Please [edit] the question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `eventi`.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results as *text tables* in your question.  Your description and code are not compatible.

Comment: Im sorry for the confusion, forgot to say that I extracted month1 and year1 etc before passing to the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a concept (assuming the data is valid, i.e. the end of some event is always later than its start):

1. If you want at least a day of a given month be in the event:

```sql
SELECT * FROM e
WHERE e.startevent <= '2019-04-30' AND e.endevent >= '2019-04-01'
```

2. If you want the entire month be in the event:

```sql
SELECT * FROM e
WHERE e.startevent <= '2019-04-01' AND e.endevent >= '2019-04-30'
```

Comment: Thank you This works for me. Now my problem is how to add [SOLVED] :)

Comment: @JoshuaWhopper You can tick a checkmark near the desired answer and the question will count as solved.

Answer (score 1):

If you want overlapping time intervals, then it is something like this:

```
SELECT e.*
FROM eventi e
WHERE e.startevent < '2019-05-01' AND -- starts before the end of the month
      e.endevent > '2019-04-01'       -- ends after the start of the month
```